# Tidy or other clever methods to importing .accdb tables into R

Tags: r, ms-access, lapply, rodbc, dbplyr

I am attempting to import all of the tables within a relational MS Access database (.accdb) into R as separate data.frames.  I have previously relied upon dbplyr and RMariaDB when accessing relational SQL databases stored online and I was under initial impressions that I could appropriate some of the methods to this .accdb, but I am becoming persuaded I was mistaken.

I have accomplished what I wanted to do with this code:

```
#### Libraries =================================================================
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

#### Import database ===========================================================
# Define connection strings
dbq_string <- paste0("DBQ=", getwd(),"my_database.accdb")
driver_string <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
db_connect_string <- paste0(driver_string, dbq_string)

# Create .accdb connection
con <- odbcDriverConnect(db_connect_string)

#### Extract tables to data.frames
table1 <- sqlFetch(con, "tbltable1")
table2 <- sqlFetch(con, "tbltable2")
table3 <- sqlFetch(con, "tbltable3")
```

I am seeking advice on two topics here:
1.) Is there a tidyverse way of going about this?  I've previously used code like:

```
table1 <- tbl(con, "tbltable1")
Table1 <- table1 %>% select(my_col) %>% collect()
```

is this not possible grammar for working through Access?

2.) Can my code where I am extracting tables to data.frames be refined by an apply-family function?  I previously experimented with functions to get all of the table names (table_names) and pass it as an argument to an apply function to assign each table.  I was under the impression that something like `lapply(table1, sqlFetch, con)` would do it, but I receive an error indicating improper table connection.

Comment: I don't have an Access database to test on, but dbplyr includes a `simulate_access` function which suggests you should be able to use the approach `table = tbl(con, "tablename")`. What happens when you try it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390093/7742981) answer, you need to use the DBI package to connect to a database in order to then use dbplyr. You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816062/connect-ms-access-database-to-r) question helpful.

Once you have successfully connected R and Access, then yes I would suggest:

```r
table1 <- tbl(con, "tbltable1")
Table1 <- table1 %>% select(my_col) %>% collect()
```

As a good tidyverse way of approaching reading all the tables into R.

If you want to do this with `lapply`, then the key thing is probably to name the extra arguments.

```r
table_names = c("table1", "table2", "table3")

all_tables = lapply(table_names, sqlFetch, channel = con)
```

Will likely work. But omitting the `channel =` may fail (because `channel` is an argument for `sqlFetch` not for `lapply`).

Doing this in a tidyverse way, perhaps something like:

```r
read_tbl = function(con, tbl_name){
  tbl(con, tbl_name) %>% collect()
}

all_tables = lapply(table_names, read_tbl, con = con)
```